# jQuery get current click event for element and append to it

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid and adding my own onclick event to each cell of data when the grid has completed rendering.

jqGrid has default behavior of highlighting a row onclick.  When I add my own onclick event after the grid renders, my event overwrites the jqGrid event as expected.  I would like to preserve the jqGrid onclick event and just add my event to it.

How can I get the current onclick event for all elements matching a certain class and just append more actions to the event?  This is my current new onclick event.

Thanks!

```
$(".searchOrders").click(function() {
    $('#tabs').tabs('url', 2, '/view/dspOrders.cfm?id_orders='+$(this).attr('title'));
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 2);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery event binding mechanism isn't one that overwrites. In other words:

```
 $("#button").click(function() { alert("hello"); });
 $("#button").click(function() { alert("goodbye"); });
```

has two events fired on #button, the second one doesn't overwrite the first.

Something else is going on here.

Comment: Oh boy, duh!  The other onclick events are on the table cell and my new events are on the anchor within the cell.  Just noticed that now.

Answer (score 3):

Use the jqGrid onCellSelect event. [jqGrid Docs](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events)

Answer (score 0):

you can adapt some code i use to insert a load event:

```
// stack the original loads
var aryLoadQueue = new Array();
$.each($.data($main.get(0), "events").load, function() {
    aryLoadQueue.push(this);
});

...

// put the original loads back in place to take place after our one-time load
$(aryLoadQueue).each(function() {
    $main.load(this);
});
```

feel free to comment with questions...